# Postgres simple 'pivot' table

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table of data as such

```
name   |   type   |  count

test   | blue     |  6
test2  | red      |  3
test   | red      |  4
```

How can I query it such that I get a table:

```
name  |  num_red  | num_blue

test  | 4         | 6
test2 | 3         | 0
```

I can of course select count(*) where type=blue etc but I can't think of how to count multiple types within one query like this.

Thanks!

Comment: This is fairly basic SQL, so rather than using John's answer verbatim I strongly recommend you read the PostgreSQL tutorial and user manual so you understand *why* it works and how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in you select clause.

```
SELECT  name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'red' THEN "count" ELSE 0 END) numred,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'blue' THEN "count" ELSE 0 END) numblue
FROM tableName
GROUP BY name
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4aaa9/3)

Comment: how to do dynamic pivot without crosstab !