# How to pivot a Table in POSTGRESQL 8.4

Tags: postgresql

I have following table:

```
|Type | Year | amount |
_______________________
|t1   | 2001 | 40     |
|t1   | 2000 | 50     |
|t2   | 2003 | 30     |
|t2   | 2003 | 20     |
|t3   | 2004 | 10     |
```

and I would like to show it as:

```
   | type |2001 |2000 |2003 |2004|
   |______________________________
   | t1   |40   |50   |0    |0   |
   | t2   | 0   |0    | 50  |0   |
   | t3   |0    |0    | 0   |10  |
```

I don't want to hard code the years and I need to do that in POstgresql 8.4, which doesn't support:

```
CREATE EXTENSION
IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
```

I have pivoted table before, using following code: [more explanation for the following code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939766/postgres-simple-pivot-table)

```
 sum(CASE
             WHEN year = 2000 THEN
               total
             ELSE 0
           END)
```

In which the `total =sum (amount)` in each year and I had calculated it in another CTE. But at that time the years were already known but for the above table I need to loop through the years and read each and then calculate the `sum(amount)` and the years may change in the main table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres simple 'pivot' table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939766/postgres-simple-pivot-table)

Comment: This is different I explained how; Please let me know if it needs more clarification. using that example, the years should be already known, while in my question it's not predetermined and it should be read from table each time

Comment: This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query might be of use.  It mentions an article [Automatically creating pivot table column names in PostgreSQL](http://www.cureffi.org/2013/03/19/automatically-creating-pivot-table-column-names-in-postgresql/) in which the author writes `I run PostgreSQL 9.2 but I believe this should work at least as far back as 8.4`.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it doesn't work in version 8.4

Comment: Did you try it?  If so, how far did you get?  The general approach of running a query to get the years you want and running a query with a bunch of case statements for those years should work for any sql database so I'm curious as to what part of that didn't work.  It might be something silly you can fix.

Comment: Yes I tried it on 9 and it worked but when I try it on 8.4 it throws an error for CREATE EXTENSION
IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

Comment: @Verver http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=66991aae158f19fac7281129fed1948d

Comment: Works great! That's exactly what I want. Thank you Abelisto. I wish you had replied as an Answer so that I can mark it as Answer